# HtmlAgilityPack multiple tbody in table

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack

There are multiple Tbodies in a table and I am trying to parse them out by using HTMLagilitypack. Normally the code below would work but it doesn't. Right now it only prints the first tbody and ignores the 2nd.

**Code**

```
var tableOffense =  doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//table[@id='OFF']");
                var tbody = tableOffense.SelectNodes("tbody");
                foreach(var bodies in tbody)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("id "+offender.offenderId +" "+ Utilities.RemoveHtmlCharacters(bodies.InnerText));
                }
```

**HTML**

```
<table id="OFF" class="centerTable" cols="2" style="margin-top:0; width:100%;" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">   
<tbody>
<!-- %%$SPLIT  -->
  <tr>         <th id="offenseCodeColHdr" scope="row" style="width:25%;" class="uline">Offense Code</th>         <td headers="offenseCodeColHdr" class="uline">288(a)</td>          </tr>       <tr>         <th id="descriptionColHdr" scope="row" style="width:25%;" class="uline">Description</th>         <td headers="descriptionColHdr" class="uline">LEWD OR LASCIVIOUS ACTS WITH A CHILD UNDER 14 YEARS OF AGE</td>             </tr>           <tr>         <th id="lastConvictionColHdr" scope="row" style="width:25%;" class="uline">Year of Last Conviction</th>         <td headers="lastConvictionColHdr" class="uline">&nbsp;</td>       </tr>       <tr>          <th id="lastReleaseColHdr" scope="row" style="width:25%;" class="uline">Year of Last Release</th>         <td headers="lastReleaseColHdr" class="uline">&nbsp;</td>       </tr>
  <tr><th colspan="2"><hr style="height:2px;background-color:#000;"></th></tr>         </tbody>
<!-- %%$SPLIT  -->
  <tbody><tr>         <th id="offenseCodeColHdr" scope="row" style="width:25%;" class="uline">Offense Code</th>         <td headers="offenseCodeColHdr" class="uline">261(a)(2)</td>            </tr>       <tr>         <th id="descriptionColHdr" scope="row" style="width:25%;" class="uline">Description</th>         <td headers="descriptionColHdr" class="uline">RAPE BY FORCE OR FEAR</td>          </tr>           <tr>         <th id="lastConvictionColHdr" scope="row" style="width:25%;" class="uline">Year of Last Conviction</th>         <td headers="lastConvictionColHdr" class="uline">&nbsp;</td>       </tr>       <tr>          <th id="lastReleaseColHdr" scope="row" style="width:25%;" class="uline">Year of Last Release</th>         <td headers="lastReleaseColHdr" class="uline">&nbsp;</td>       </tr>
  <tr><th colspan="2"><hr style="height:2px;background-color:#000;"></th></tr>         </tbody>
<!-- %%$SPLIT  -->
</table>
```

I've printed just the tableOffense node by itself to make sure the 2nd tbody exists at load and it does.

**Question**
Why does the code only print out the first tbody and not both?

Comment: I can only see one tbody node in your Html code. Is this just a part of your html code in question?

Comment: @Serv fixed it yeah it was only a part by accident

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't figured out why your code only gives you one tbody, but may I suggest an alternative solution, to select all your `<tbody>` elements?

Personally I would make use of XPAth and just select all tbody elements in one go, without an additional `SelectNodes()`:

```
var tbody = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//table[@id='OFF']//tbody");
foreach (var elem in tbody)
{
    //Dump only works in LinqPad
    elem.InnerText.Dump();
}
```

Edit:

The following code (your code) also yields the same results

```
var tableOffense =  doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//table[@id='OFF']");
var tbody = tableOffense.SelectNodes("//tbody");
```